# cast string to array of structs then look up values in another table SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I currently have a string which represents a list of structs in my table. I want to look up values in another table based on the values of elements in the struct.

For example, below, the car info struct is [spare, carType, carColour].

```
╔═══════════════════════════╗
║          CarInfo          ║
╠═══════════════════════════╣
║ “[1,1,1]”                 ║
║ “[1,2,1] [1,1,2]”         ║
║ null                      ║
║ “[1,2,1] [1,1,2] [1,1,1]” ║
╚═══════════════════════════╝
```

and I want to look up the table:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════════╦══╗
║ CarTypeId ║ CarTypeString ║ CarColourId ║ CarColourString ║  ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══╣
║         1 ║ "Hyundai"     ║           1 ║ "Red"           ║  ║
║         1 ║ "Hyundai"     ║           2 ║ "Blue"          ║  ║
║         2 ║ "Toyota"      ║           1 ║ "Green"         ║  ║
║         2 ║ "Toyota"      ║           2 ║ "Yellow"        ║  ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════════╩══╝
```

and obtain the following result:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                       CarInfo                       ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ “[1,Hyundai,Red]”                                   ║
║ “[1,Toyota,Green] [1,Hyundai,Blue]”                 ║
║ null                                                ║
║ “[1,Toyota,Green] [1,Hyundai,Blue] [1,Hyundai,Red]” ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I've found out that I can split the strings into arrays with someString.split(CarInfo,' ') but thereafter I'm not sure how to do the cast to struct or the "looped" left join after.

Comment: clarify: in the carInfo table what exactly data type of the column? having exact table schema will help a lot to understand your use case!

Comment: It is a string.

Comment: so double quotes are part of the string or you added them to emphases that they are strings?

Comment: also, in lookup table `"Hyundai"` - are double quotes actually part of value or just way to show that it is a string?

Comment: In both cases, I added them to emphasis they were strings, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT STRING_AGG('[' || spare || ',' || carTypeString || ',' || carColourString || ']', ' ') AS CarInfo
FROM `project.dataset.cars` t
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(CarInfo, ' ')) info,
UNNEST([STRUCT(
  SPLIT(TRIM(info, '[]'))[OFFSET(0)] AS spare, 
  CAST(SPLIT(TRIM(info, '[]'))[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) AS carTypeId, 
  CAST(SPLIT(TRIM(info, '[]'))[OFFSET(2)] AS INT64) AS carColourId
)])
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.lookup` l
USING(carTypeId, carColourId)
GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', t)
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.cars` AS (
  SELECT '[1,1,1]' CarInfo UNION ALL
  SELECT '[1,2,1] [1,1,2]' UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT '[1,2,1] [1,1,2] [1,1,1]'
), `project.dataset.lookup` AS (
  SELECT 1 CarTypeId, 'Hyundai' CarTypeString, 1 CarColourId, 'Red' CarColourString UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Hyundai', 2, 'Blue' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Toyota', 1, 'Green' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Toyota', 2, 'Yellow'
)
SELECT STRING_AGG('[' || spare || ',' || carTypeString || ',' || carColourString || ']', ' ') AS CarInfo
FROM `project.dataset.cars` t
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(CarInfo, ' ')) info,
UNNEST([STRUCT(
  SPLIT(TRIM(info, '[]'))[OFFSET(0)] AS spare, 
  CAST(SPLIT(TRIM(info, '[]'))[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) AS carTypeId, 
  CAST(SPLIT(TRIM(info, '[]'))[OFFSET(2)] AS INT64) AS carColourId
)])
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.lookup` l
USING(carTypeId, carColourId)
GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', t)
```

output is

```
Row CarInfo  
1   [1,Hyundai,Red]  
2   [1,Toyota,Green] [1,Hyundai,Blue]    
3   null     
4   [1,Toyota,Green] [1,Hyundai,Blue] [1,Hyundai,Red]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, amazing. 
I have an additional quick question. If I have another column in the CarInfo table to start with and I want to keep it at the end. What is the best way to keep it when using the GroupBy?
I see elsewhere others do Max(additionalCol) as additionalCol?

Comment: that's exactly the way to go with :o) just add it to your most outer select